# Does the *.p12 file or the *.pem file contains the url of the Certificate Authority?

Tags: ssl, encryption, https, public-key-encryption

My understanding regarding the https protocol is the publickey of the web server which needs to be visited should be received from the Central Authority like verizon.

If that is the case then the url of the central authority must be present in the pem file which the browser holds. But there is no information regarding the url of the CA. Then how does the browser gets the public key of the web server it wants to visit.

Comment: You are jumping from file format to some URL attribute in CA certificate to public key of a particular web server. Can you clarify what exactly are you trying to ask?

Comment: Where does the browser gets the url of the CA ?

Comment: Does it at all? If you mean [OCSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Online_Certificate_Status_Protocol) then the certificate *can* contain AuthorityInfoAccess extension that *can* contain the address of the OCSP responder. Whether the particular certificate contains it and whether the particular browser pays any attention to it is another question.

Comment: "how does the browser gets the public key of the web server it wants to visit" - the server sends its certificate in the `ServerHello`. The `ServerHello` is sent in response to the `ClientHello`. Additionally, the `ServerHello` *should* contain intermediate certificates required to build a path to the trusted root certificate. The trusted root certificate is *not* sent - the client must have it and trust it. There's other security models and designs too. For example, DANE puts certificates and public keys in DNS.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming. See [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center.

Comment: The address of the *web server* is encoded in the certificate. This is not a dynamic service; you get a certificate for a specific server address and that's it.